# Linking a Tkinter slider to text entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am currently trying to create a GUI in python using Tkinter. I was just wondering if there is a way to set the limits on a slider, based on an input into a text entry field. Below is the text entry I would like to link the slider to.

```
#tunnel height
self.height = Tkinter.StringVar()
self.height_entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.height)
self.height_entry.grid(column=3,row=2,sticky='EW')
self.height_entry.bind("<Return>",self.OnPressEnter)
self.height.set("5.95")

self.height_label = Tkinter.StringVar()
label=Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.height_label,
anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
label.grid(column=3,row=3,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
self.height_label.set("Sets the test section height")
```

I would like the upper limit of the slider to vary between 1, and the entry into the height box, but cannot find a way to do this.

Sorry if this has been asked before

Answer (score 1):

You can change the parameters of the `Scale` using `configure`. Just put this into the method that's called when the input of the `Entry` is changed. Also, if you want a number, better use an `IntVar`.

```
var = IntVar()
text = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
scale = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient='horizontal')
text.bind("<Return>", lambda event: scale.configure(to=var.get()))
```